# How do you connect to a node from the server side of a meteor app

Tags: meteor, ethereum, web3js

This is the command I am using to run the node (a private testnet)

```
geth --networkid 420 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

This is the code I am using to connect to the node on the server side of my app

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
```

If I try `web3.isConnected()` on the server side it returns false

I also tried `console.log(web3.net.listening)` as recommended by the comments but this gave the error:

```
TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function
```

I can connect fine on the client side and `web3.isConnected()` returns true

I am running the app locally on my computer

Comment: Seems like an issue with web3, try adding `target: 'node'` to your `webpack.config.js` - https://github.com/uzyn/web3-loader/issues/11#issuecomment-220352465

Comment: @d4nyll do you know where webpack.config.js is located?

Comment: @d4nyll I found the file but where in the file do you add target: 'node' ?

Comment: I think it's in the top-level of th JSON -
 https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/ (FYI this doc is for Webpack 2)